# Making WebWorkers a safe environment

Tags: javascript, web-worker

In a quest to have an interface capable of running arbitrary javascript code inside the browser, without having a security hole the size of a typical yo-mama joke, [Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) proposed using [Web Workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html). They run in a semi-sandboxed environment (no DOM access and already inside the browser) and can be killed so the user can't put them in an infinite loop.

Here's the example he brought up: http://tuohiniemi.fi/~runeli/petka/workertest.html (open your console)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwgKn/4/) (Google chrome only)

Now, this seems like a good solution; however, is it a complete (or approaching complete) one? Is there anything obvious missing?

The entire thing (as it's hooked up to a bot) can be found on github: [worker](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/blob/master/source/codeWorker.js), [evaluator](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/blob/master/source/eval.js)

main:

```
workercode = "worker.js";

function makeWorkerExecuteSomeCode( code, callback ) {
    var timeout;

    code = code + "";
    var worker = new Worker( workercode );

    worker.addEventListener( "message", function(event) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        callback( event.data );
    });

    worker.postMessage({
        code: code
    });

    timeout = window.setTimeout( function() {
        callback( "Maximum execution time exceeded" );
        worker.terminate();
    }, 1000 );
}

makeWorkerExecuteSomeCode( '5 + 5', function(answer){
    console.log( answer );
});

makeWorkerExecuteSomeCode( 'while(true);', function(answer){
    console.log( answer );
});

var kertoma = 'function kertoma(n){return n === 1 ? 1 : n * kertoma(n-1)}; kertoma(15);';

makeWorkerExecuteSomeCode( kertoma, function(answer){
    console.log( answer );
});
```

worker:

```
var global = this;

/* Could possibly create some helper functions here so they are always available when executing code in chat?*/

/* Most extra functions could be possibly unsafe */

    var wl = {
        "self": 1,
        "onmessage": 1,
        "postMessage": 1,
        "global": 1,
        "wl": 1,
        "eval": 1,
        "Array": 1,
        "Boolean": 1,
        "Date": 1,
        "Function": 1,
        "Number" : 1,
        "Object": 1,
        "RegExp": 1,
        "String": 1,
        "Error": 1,
        "EvalError": 1,
        "RangeError": 1,
        "ReferenceError": 1,
        "SyntaxError": 1,
        "TypeError": 1,
        "URIError": 1,
        "decodeURI": 1,
        "decodeURIComponent": 1,
        "encodeURI": 1,
        "encodeURIComponent": 1,
        "isFinite": 1,
        "isNaN": 1,
        "parseFloat": 1,
        "parseInt": 1,
        "Infinity": 1,
        "JSON": 1,
        "Math": 1,
        "NaN": 1,
        "undefined": 1
    };

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames( global ).forEach( function( prop ) {
        if( !wl.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
            Object.defineProperty( global, prop, {
                get : function() {
                    throw new Error( "Security Exception: cannot access "+prop);
                    return 1;
                }, 
                configurable : false
            });    
        }
    });

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames( global.__proto__ ).forEach( function( prop ) {
        if( !wl.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
            Object.defineProperty( global.__proto__, prop, {
                get : function() {
                    throw new Error( "Security Exception: cannot access "+prop);
                    return 1;
                }, 
                configurable : false
            });    
        }
    });




onmessage = function( event ) {
    "use strict";
    var code = event.data.code;
    var result;
    try {
        result = eval( '"use strict";\n'+code );
    }
    catch(e){
        result = e.toString();
    }
    postMessage( "(" + typeof result + ")" + " " + result );
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't they still be able to send AJAX requests?

Comment: @SLaks The worker has XHR set to `null`

Comment: @SLaks You can manually remove a bunch of insecure properties yourselves, as shown in the example.

Comment: It appears that if you `delete` a native/host object, it will be restored in its original state. `"delete XMLHttpRequest; XMLHttpRequest;"` Will return the original XMLHttpRequest object. There must be a way around this :/

Comment: Nvm, a work around was suggested by @copy. Editing in

Comment: Frankly, this is brilliant. I wish I could give you more rep for this.

Comment: You have the blacklist of functions, that are unsafe. It doesn't look good. What if new standard or browser defines new unsafe functions?

Comment: I think you need whitelist - remove all functions, except those that you know they are safe.

Comment: @zch I just noticed this when I enumerated over global object in worker. I am making a whitelist approach. Thanks

Comment: @zch we are using whitelist approach now, how does it look?

Comment: As a paranoid I would add some kind of runtime test, that your method actually blocks something on working system. Otherwise, looks okay, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: How about using something like: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/ ?

Comment: Maybe running a VM such as [continuum](https://github.com/Benvie/continuum) could be an idea?

Comment: @IdoGreen That'd require incorporating a huge outside framework. A native solution is preferred.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine That's learning to the preferable, but comes with a huge performance kill

Comment: What exact workaround was added to prevent delete keyword from undoing it? @Esailija

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The current code (listed below) has been now in use in the Stackoverflow javascript chat room for a while
and so far the toughest problem was `Array(5000000000).join("adasdadadasd")` instantly crashing some
browser tabs for me when I was running the code executor bot. Monkeypatching `Array.prototype.join` seems to have fixed this and the maximum
execution time of 50ms has worked for any other attempt to hog memory or crash the browser.

```
var global = this;

/* Could possibly create some helper functions here so they are always available when executing code in chat?*/

/* Most extra functions could be possibly unsafe */

var wl = {
    "self": 1,
    "onmessage": 1,
    "postMessage": 1,
    "global": 1,
    "wl": 1,
    "eval": 1,
    "Array": 1,
    "Boolean": 1,
    "Date": 1,
    "Function": 1,
    "Number" : 1,
    "Object": 1,
    "RegExp": 1,
    "String": 1,
    "Error": 1,
    "EvalError": 1,
    "RangeError": 1,
    "ReferenceError": 1,
    "SyntaxError": 1,
    "TypeError": 1,
    "URIError": 1,
    "decodeURI": 1,
    "decodeURIComponent": 1,
    "encodeURI": 1,
    "encodeURIComponent": 1,
    "isFinite": 1,
    "isNaN": 1,
    "parseFloat": 1,
    "parseInt": 1,
    "Infinity": 1,
    "JSON": 1,
    "Math": 1,
    "NaN": 1,
    "undefined": 1
};

Object.getOwnPropertyNames( global ).forEach( function( prop ) {
    if( !wl.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
        Object.defineProperty( global, prop, {
            get : function() {
                throw "Security Exception: cannot access "+prop;
                return 1;
            }, 
            configurable : false
        });    
    }
});

Object.getOwnPropertyNames( global.__proto__ ).forEach( function( prop ) {
    if( !wl.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
        Object.defineProperty( global.__proto__, prop, {
            get : function() {
                throw "Security Exception: cannot access "+prop;
                return 1;
            }, 
            configurable : false
        });    
    }
});

Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype, "join", {

    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,

    value: function(old){
        return function(arg){
            if( this.length > 500 || (arg && arg.length > 500 ) ) {
                throw "Exception: too many items";
            }

            return old.apply( this, arguments );
        };
    }(Array.prototype.join)

});


(function(){
    var cvalues = [];

    var console = {
        log: function(){
            cvalues = cvalues.concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) );
        }
    };

    function objToResult( obj ) {
        var result = obj;
        switch( typeof result ) {
            case "string":
                return '"' + result + '"';
                break;
            case "number":
            case "boolean":
            case "undefined":
            case "null":
            case "function":
                return result + "";
                break;
            case "object":
                if( !result ) {
                    return "null";
                }
                else if( result.constructor === Object || result.constructor === Array ) {
                    var type = ({}).toString.call( result );
                    var stringified;
                    try {
                        stringified = JSON.stringify(result);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        return ""+e;
                    }
                    return type + " " + stringified;
                }
                else {
                    return ({}).toString.call( result );
                }
                break;

        }

    }

    onmessage = function( event ) {
        "use strict";
        var code = event.data.code;
        var result;
        try {
            result = eval( '"use strict";\n'+code );
        }
        catch(e) {
            postMessage( e.toString() );
            return;
        }
        result = objToResult( result );
        if( cvalues && cvalues.length ) {
            result = result + cvalues.map( function( value, index ) {
                return "Console log "+(index+1)+":" + objToResult(value);
            }).join(" ");
        }
        postMessage( (""+result).substr(0,400) );
    };

})();
```

Comment: Why are Math, and parse* functions disabled?

Comment: @Domi why do you think they are disabled

Comment: @Esailija So far, I only found [cross-domain Math.random() prediction](http://ifsec.blogspot.tw/2012/05/cross-domain-mathrandom-prediction.html). But since the attacker cannot communicate to the outside world, it seems to be harmless.

Comment: Btw, I am also disallowing `XMLHttpRequest`, `Worker`, `WebSocket` and `importScripts`. How do you guys cope with that?

Comment: @Domi I think you are misunderstanding - this is a whitelist approach. Anything not listed is disallowed while only the things that are listed are allowed. Whitelist is better because it doesn't require updating when new APIs are implemented.

Comment: What would happen if any of the insecure properties are already non-configurable?

Comment: @Bergi that is not happening in the use case

Comment: How do you know that for future APIs? :-) But I've checked it now, `Object.defineProperty` would throw and prevent the `onmessage` handler from being set up.

Comment: I tried this in Chrome, and it reported "cannot redefine property [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)". Adding it to the whitelist fixed it.

Comment: One more stupid question: What is dangerous about allowing `console`? Is that also part of making it "future-proof", or can it currently be exploited?

Comment: @Domi I don't think there is a `console` in a web worker

Comment: @Esailija there is, at least on Chrome and IE. Been using it for quite a while already. I am guessing that it is running on its own thread.

Comment: @Esailija bad news: There is a Chrome bug (or feature?) where a whole bunch of globals are not listed by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, including all *Timeout and *Interval functions. [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WuhrP/) shows a rather long list of such globals (at least in Chrome). This script won't run in IE because it uses in-line Workers (The current IE version disallows running workers from `Blob` URLs, for some stupid reason).

Comment: @Domi that's not a bug and those are found by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( global.__proto__ )`

Comment: @Esailija That is not true. `global.__proto__` only finds two additional globals in my Chrome: `constructor` and `postMessage`. The rest is still missing, including *Timeout and *Interval functions. [See this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WuhrP/1/) for proof.

Comment: @Domi *Timeout and *Interval function are listed http://jsfiddle.net/WuhrP/2/ (I am using version 33.0.1750.152)

Comment: @Esailija Apologies, my code probably had a bug then. Anyway, would you mind taking a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078059/is-it-possible-to-read-local-variables-of-parent-stackframes)?

Comment: @Esailija The code in your answer looks like the one in the question. You might want to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26798249/1906307).

Comment: Is there any way for code in the WebWorker to undo the disabling, eg with delete keyword?

Comment: Hi @Esailija, are you still using this code in stackoverflow chat?

Answer (score 6):

The code currently (2014-11-07) shown in the question despite ostensibly disallowing access to `XMLHttpRequest` (since it is not whitelisted), still allows code to access it.

If I put the code in the question (or the accepted answer) in a web page and worker combo and execute the following code on Chrome 38:

```
makeWorkerExecuteSomeCode('event.target.XMLHttpRequest', function (answer) { console.log( answer ); });
```

The result is:

```
function XMLHttpRequest() { [native code] }
```

However it does not work in FF. Bug in Chrome?

Another thing I found but which does not seem to lead very far down the rabit hole is reinstating `console.log`. This works on FF 31 but not Chrome 38:

```
makeWorkerExecuteSomeCode(
    'var c = self.__proto__.__proto__.__lookupGetter__("console").call(self); c.log("FOO");', 
    function (answer) { console.log(answer) });
```

This would log `"FOO"` to the console without passing through the fake `console.log` that the web worker provides. The code above uses `self`, which can be blacklisted (by removing it from the whitelist) but `this` and `global` also work. I've found that attempts to blacklist `global` fail on FF and Chrome: the worker dies with an error.

Note: Chrome refuses to blacklist `Intl` so it has to be added to the whitelist for the code to run at all.

Comment: Very good point concerning the hole in Chrome 38, but that is rather easy to fill: Just put a closure around the `try/catch` in `onmessage` and redefine `event` with `var event;` within the closure.

Comment: So is there any real solution?