# Using Google Caja to run user-supplied Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-caja

It appears that the [official examples](https://developers.google.com/caja/docs/gettingstarted/) use a [caja.js](https://caja.appspot.com/caja.js) file that just wraps an `iframe` to load an URL from a server hosting a caja compilation service, which in turn, gets its input from some URL. The relevant API for that is available [here](http://google-caja.googlecode.com/svn/doc/cajajs/index.html).

However, what I really want is to just safely (and repeatedly) run a user-supplied piece of Javascript, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    var x = getUserResult(currentState);
    updateState(currentState, x);
}
```

Is there any way to do this directly? The code [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) has the compiler. Why can't I just use that to compile the code and then run that within an emulated context? Is it because the only way to get a safe context in a browser is an `iframe`? And, if so, is there any way I can use an `iframe` to directly run given source code, without having to fetch it from an external URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caja needs an `iframe` no matter what. Both modes of execution require a set of JavaScript globals (obtained by creating the frame) which is available to be radically modified to enable safe execution.

Modern Caja (ES5 mode) does not require any server-side compilation step; provided the browser is compatible you can use Caja in the standard way and the server will never be contacted. To force this, specify `es5Mode: true` in the options to `caja.initialize`.

You can load guest code once and repeatedly execute it; just provide an `api` which lets the guest pass a function out when it's loaded, then call the function whenever you like.

---

For your use case, it would also be possible to use SES, the modern safe-eval subsystem of Caja, without using Caja itself at all; this would allow you to skip having any iframes, but would require you to write your code in a SES-compatible way; that is,

- refraining from modifying global objects such as `Object.prototype`, and
- protecting all objects directly or indirectly exposed to the user-supplied code using `Object.freeze()`.)

If you're up for it, I do recommend using SES directly, as it removes a lot of indirections and total complexity, but it does require understanding the concepts to succeed at safety.

Comment: Great answer. One more question: Is there example code? Because the standard examples do not do it this way.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/caja/docs/callingguestcode/ is an example of a guest-written function being invoked by the host.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I meant an SES code example? The given examples only use iframe and guest code is always provided through a URL.

Comment: @Domi Good question. I don't know if there's really been any _example_ SES code written outside of Mark Miller's papers. I think that would be a good question to raise on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-caja-discuss) to see if anyone's memory is jogged, and if there isn't to start a discussion on what to write.

Comment: @Domi Die you habe any success on this? I would be interested in it also.

Comment: @heinob No, I had to ice that project for now. What I used was thread workers with whitelisting of "mostly safe functions", as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653809/making-webworkers-a-safe-environment/).