# Sanitizing user supplied javascript using Google Caja

Tags: sanitization, google-caja

*A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535495/using-google-caja-to-run-user-supplied-javascript), but doesn't provide a working code example.*

I want to sanitize user-submited Javascript so I can execute it in-browser.  I'm following the example code [here](https://developers.google.com/caja/docs/runningjavascript/):

```

```
caja.initialize({
  cajaServer: 'https://caja.appspot.com/',
  debug: true
});

caja.load(undefined, undefined, function(frame) {
  frame.code('return function f(x) { return 1; }', 'application/javascript')
    .run();
});
```

```

I get:

`Uncaught script error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to parse program: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:15) in source: "return function f(x) { return 1; }" at line: -1`

...any ideas?