# Is it possible to read local variables of parent stackframes?

Tags: javascript, html, security, web-worker

**Scenario**:

I am working on Javascript code that allows running arbitrary user-supplied code in a web worker environment, similar to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653809/making-webworkers-a-safe-environment/). Let's call the two parties host (launches the worker) and guest (inside the worker).

Now, I want to be able to run multiple scripts on the worker at the same time, or at least have them sent to the worker right away, without having to wait for the previous script to finish. It is crucial to reduce delay and overhead because a single "session" could take millions or even billions of script runs - the more I can do in a few seconds the better; and yes, there is a good reason as to why I am choosing Javascript (performance is important, but not the most important aspect).

However, that means that the worker somehow needs to reliably tell me when a script started and stopped. That requires some message sending, involving a unique script identifier.

**Code**:

I am currently using this code in the guest:

```
onmessage = function(event) {
    var scriptId = event.data.id;
    var cmd = event.data.cmd;
    var args = event.data.args;

    switch (cmd) {
        case "init":
            // code here to lock down the worker and disable everything potentially insecure, except for postMessage
            break;
        case "run":
            if (!workerInitialized()) return;
            // run user given code
            var code = args.code;
            // ...
            postMessage({cmd: "start", args: scriptId});        // signal that script started
            runScript(code);        // runs eval(code) with proper error reporting etc.
            postMessage({cmd: "stop", args: scriptId});         // signal that script stopped
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Problem**:

As you can see, `scriptId` exists in a stackframe above `eval(code)`. I am using some cryptographic library to generate the id so the user cannot possibly guess the id (since the worker gets killed upon any wrong guess). Also, `onmessage` cannot be overridden by `code`.

Can I make sure that `code` cannot "fake" the stop message, by peaking at the stack when the code is executed in an environment that the author of `code` cannot control (e.g. on a node server or in the browser of a different user)?

**Possible Solution**:

Send the "stop" message in `setTimeout` and hide `scriptId` in closure so it will be executed right after `code` finished execution.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2d8Ke/7/) shows that it works, but maybe I am overlooking some evil edge cases?

That means, I change the `case "run"` code to this:

```
postMessage({cmd: "start", args: scriptId});        // signal that script started
setTimeout((function(scriptId) { return function() { postMessage({cmd: "stop", args: scriptId}); };})(scriptId), 0);         // signal that script stopped, right after this function returned
scriptId = null;
runScript(code);        // runs eval(code) with proper error reporting etc.
```

Is it impossible for `code` to read `scriptId` in any execution environment? I don't even care if it can stop the timer, because the worker will be killed after a fixed timeout anyway (as long as it cannot fake the `stop` message which will stop that "timeout timer"!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is not possible for code to read scriptId in any execution environment?

Yes. Code can only access variables in its current scope (of the [execution context](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3)), not local variables from scopes on the call stack.

However, eval'd code *can* access and possibly overwrite/intercept the global `postMessage` and `onmessage` functions. If you have prevented that, they still would be able to call them, so you need to verify that the calls came from your worker manager and not from the custom code. If you have ensured that, everything should be fine.

Notice that when you're running multiple scripts in the same "worker session", you might need to clean up the global scope after each run (or prevent any modifications in beforehand). Otherwise, independent scripts might be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: So I did take pre-cautions: `onmessage` and `postMessage` cannot be tempered with. However, user-code can call `postMessage`, which is why it must not fake the `scriptId`: I use the "stop" message to determine that the script actually stopped (and I don't have to kill the worker after the timeout). If it can be faked, the worker timeout timer will stop and the script can keep on running, which is bad. So, the ECMA standard says its impossible for to get parent stackframe variables? FYI: The context does not need clean-up because it is one "session" (only involving code of a single author).

Comment: Uh, ECMA standard does not disallow the introduction of some kind of introspection API; yet it specifies explicitly that a plain variable name resolution just checks the parent scopes of the *current* execution context (stack frame), not searching the whole stack.

Comment: If a `stop` message is sent, you still could kill the worker, no? Btw, did you prohibit the use of `setTimeout` and other async functions, so the script might not have "stopped" after it returns control to you?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, by default `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are disallowed, I was just considering my options. So basically, as long as the user script has no access to some debugger API, it is all good? Since [I remove access to everything except for a few whitelisted globals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653809/making-webworkers-a-safe-environment?lq=1), I'm in the clear, or am I overseeing something?