# Using eval() in isolated environment

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use `eval()` to evaluate JavaScript code and be certain that that code will not have access to certain objects?

**Example:**

```
(function(window, location){ eval('console.log(window, location)'); })()
```

The above code doesn't seem to have direct access by reference to the `window` object because it is `undefined` in that scope. However, if another object exists globally and it contains a reference to `window`, it would be accessible.

If I add to `window, location` any other object or variable that may contain a reference to `window`, will the evaluated code ever be capable of referencing the `window` object?

I am trying to create a platform where user apps can be uploaded with js files and access to specific APIs will be given in the form of permissions.

Comment: Eval is Evil. Never use it if you are concerned with security.

Comment: You may want to look at some kind of [sandbox library](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox). Writing your own is probably going to lead to failure of the painful sort if there's a lot on the line here. Since you're talking about uploading and executing arbitrary JavaScript, I have no idea how `window` would factor in here. Are you running this in a browser? That seems reckless.

Comment: *In theory* I suppose that if you added *every other object* that *might* have a reference to `window` or `location`, it ought to work. Of course, the tricky part then becomes how to ensure there isn't some global object you've missed. I agree with @tadman that you should look at some ready made sandbox solutions first before you try and make your own.

Comment: eval() isn’t evil, just misunderstood

Comment: @R4nc1d That's right, it should be avoided 99% of the time, and this is a case where it may be acceptable, if you know what you are doing.

Comment: This is not for a production project, it's solely for academic purposes. I am more interested in learning wether it would be possible to create a secure sandbox environment in, let's say a webpage.

Comment: Keep in mind that with the Developer Tools i'll be always able to execute any arbitrary code on the page. So the sandbox is a little pointless here.

Comment: @KosmasPapadatos A good solution is to run the code in an isolated `iframe` that is not allowed to access the parent page. Then, even if they do modify `window`, it won't really affect your site. You can then communicate with that `iframe` using `postMessage`. That is what sites like http://jsfiddle.net/ do. You'll see that your JavaScript can't really affect the outside of the Result frame

Comment: @SharpEdge sure but this is to prevent an app from breaching the client. Not the client breaching itself.

Comment: @Juan Mendes that's the solution of JSFiddle!
Kosmas Papadatos I see now what you want, try with an iFrame, take a look at JSFiddle.

Comment: @SharpEdge Regarding your comment about dev tools, you'll only be able to execute code with your credentials. The problem with running JavaScript is that it can be run under someone else's credentials.

Comment: @JuanMendes this is a good answer. I was just hoping for something that would securely grant direct access. But then again, if infinite loops are to be taken care of, we would need a web worker for a second thread, so `postMessage` is inevitable.

Comment: @JuanMendes I mean that if the JavaScript to execute contains an infinite loop, it would freeze the whole page. We would need a web worker to do the job so that the main thread is free to declare the app non-responsive and possible terminate it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Making WebWorkers a safe environment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10653809/1048572). And that's only about WebWorkers, which are already restrained.

Comment: That is a good point, you could execute the user's code in a webworker, which doesn't have access to the window or the DOM

Comment: In conclusion I think web workers are the best solution to what I'm describing in the question. Since the `this` object always contains a reference to `window`, I guess what I'm asking is impossible. However I'm going to give this some more time in case a JavaScript Guru shows up and comes up with a way to do it :) This is highly unlikely though so if someone posts a complete answer with web workers I would go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, any function called globally (i.e. not on an object) will have its `this` parameter set to the global object (in a browser that is window). So this snippet:

```
(function(window, lovation) { eval('(function () { console.log(this) })()'); })()
```

prints out the current window object

Comment: So it is impossible to make the window object unreachable?

Comment: They could get around it by specifying what this is, e.g. `(function(window, location) { eval('(function () { console.log(this) })()'); }).call({})`

Comment: @KosmasPapadatos Pretty much. You can have a look at a sandboxing library as suggested in the comments above.

Comment: @JuanMendes that only sets `this` on the function wrapping the `eval`, the function inside the eval still has `this == window`

Comment: @WillSmith I do stand corrected ;) I did not even think about the fact that the code using `this` was inside the eval